# Using Raster calculator SAGA PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, saga

I'm trying to plus two raster images through the python interface of QGIS, i want to use the saga raster calculator, but i got one error but i don't know why:
i'm doing the following calculation (the extent of the input date is the same of the raster created by grass in this script

```
##[test]=group
##test=name
##dem=raster
##output_rast=output raster

GAUSS_1=processing.runalg('grass7:r.surf.gauss', '0.0','15','219818.5071000000461936,245558.5071000000461936,6140993.5039999997243285 ,6177833.5039999997243285',30.0,None)
DEM_Gauss=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', dem,[GAUSS_1],'a+b',False,7,output_rast)
```

but the code fails, anyone can see the error from this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error

the object derivated from the raster calculator must have the prefix 'output_' and the raster calculator must have the string ['object']
so, the code will work with the following line:

```
output_DEM_Gauss=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', dem,GAUSS_1['output'],'a+b',False,7,output_rast)
```